# Can I still use Visual Composer Website Builder after upgrading to WordPress 5.0?

Tags: visual-editor

I have a bunch of pages on a WordPress site I'm going to work on made with Visual Composer Website Builder. Given 5.0 was just released a couple days ago, I'm wondering if I should upgrade before working on them. Would it break VC?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade visual composes to latest version. Their changelog says latest version is compatible with WordPress 5.0. After upgrading VC you can safely update wordpress core to 5.0.